# writing/allocating list of strings in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, malloc

I'm making a list of strings in C, and I couldn't find anything online to easily add to and then clear a list of strings.  This would be close to Perl's "push" function.

I would like to share the code I've come up with here:

```
#include <stdio.h>//printf
#include <stdlib.h>//EXIT_FAILURE, malloc, realloc
#include <string.h>//need for strcmp and strlen

void *add_name(char **restrict array, size_t *restrict size, size_t *restrict number_of_names, const char *restrict NAME) {//this function works, when freed inside main()
    for (unsigned int name = *number_of_names-1; name <= 0; name--) {
        if (strcmp(array[name], NAME) == 0) {
            return array;//if this name is already in the list, don't add it
        }
    }
    const size_t NAME_SIZE = strlen(NAME)*sizeof(char)+sizeof(char*);
    *size += NAME_SIZE;
    array = realloc(array, *size);
    if (array == NULL) {
        puts("realloc of array failed.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    array[*number_of_names] = malloc(NAME_SIZE);
    if (array[*number_of_names] == NULL) {
        printf("alloc of array[%zu] failed.\n", *number_of_names);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    strcpy(array[*number_of_names], NAME);
    *number_of_names += 1;
    return array;
}

void *clear_names(char **restrict array, size_t *restrict size, size_t *restrict number_of_names) {//empty the list of names
    for (size_t name = 0; name < *number_of_names; name++) {
        free(array[name]); array[name] = NULL;//this is missing something
        if (array[name] != NULL) {
            printf("free of array[%zu] failed.\n", name);
        }
    }
    *number_of_names = 0;
    *size = sizeof(char);
    array = realloc(array, *size);
    if (array == NULL) {
        printf("realloc of array failed @ line %u\n",__LINE__);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return array;
}

int main (void) {
    puts("This program demonstrates how to add to and clear a list of names.");
    size_t name_list_size = sizeof(char);
    char **name_list = malloc(name_list_size);
    size_t number_of_names = 0;
    name_list = add_name(name_list, &name_list_size, &number_of_names, "James");
    name_list = add_name(name_list, &name_list_size, &number_of_names, "Mary");
    name_list = add_name(name_list, &name_list_size, &number_of_names, "Mary");
    name_list = add_name(name_list, &name_list_size, &number_of_names, "Thomas");
    for (size_t name = 0; name < number_of_names; name++) {
        printf("%s\n",name_list[name]);
    }
    name_list = clear_names(name_list, &name_list_size, &number_of_names);
//
    name_list = add_name(name_list, &name_list_size, &number_of_names, "Matthew");
    name_list = add_name(name_list, &name_list_size, &number_of_names, "Mark");
    name_list = add_name(name_list, &name_list_size, &number_of_names, "Luke");
    name_list = add_name(name_list, &name_list_size, &number_of_names, "John");
    for (size_t name = 0; name < number_of_names; name++) {
        printf("%s\n",name_list[name]);
    }
//
    name_list = clear_names(name_list, &name_list_size, &number_of_names);
    name_list = add_name(name_list, &name_list_size, &number_of_names, "Titus");
    printf("size = %zu  number_of_names = %zu\n", name_list_size, number_of_names);
    name_list = add_name(name_list, &name_list_size, &number_of_names, "Peter");
    printf("size = %zu  number_of_names = %zu\n", name_list_size, number_of_names);
    name_list = add_name(name_list, &name_list_size, &number_of_names, "Bartholomew");
    printf("size = %zu  number_of_names = %zu\n", name_list_size, number_of_names);
    name_list = add_name(name_list, &name_list_size, &number_of_names, "Paul");
    printf("size = %zu  number_of_names = %zu\n", name_list_size, number_of_names);
    for (size_t name = 0; name < number_of_names; name++) {
        printf("%s\n",name_list[name]);
    }
    name_list = clear_names(name_list, &name_list_size, &number_of_names);
    free(name_list); name_list = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with your current code that you want to fix?

Comment: You have a few problems, like not allocating enough memory to begin with, and `add_name` does not return the correct type. The compiler should warn you about many things, listen to it.

Comment: Joshua Smith - I just wanted to share something I wrote, not a question.  I checked the box that I wanted to share knowledge

Comment: some programmer dude - Neither gcc nor clang gave any warnings, perhaps you could elaborate?

Comment: Please read: [ask]

Comment: `char **name_list = malloc(name_list_size);` --> `char **name_list = malloc(sizeof(char*));` at least. Simply compiling with the `-Wall` flag will turn on several warnings.

Comment: Hi Yano,

I already compiled with -Wall flag. No warnings given.  I'm afraid you may misunderstand, name_list_size needs to adjust its size according to the string.  Your suggestion, 'malloc(sizeof(char*))', would give a segfault.

Answer (score 0):

I would offer the following suggestions:

- assign `realloc` to a temporary pointer, so if it returns NULL you don't destroy `array`
- use `strdup` instead of `malloc` for the string storage
- use `lsearch` to check & insert the string
- when increasing the size of `array`, do it by doubling instead of linearly
- package the array, its count & capacity in a `struct` (see below), and pass that as an argument to the add & clear functions

You'll need to add a comparison function to pass to `lsearch`.  If `lsearch` adds a name, it updates the count.  Allocation is still up to you, so make sure capacity exceeds count before calling it.

If you do this, I think you'll find your code is smaller and simpler.  It will also lend itself to adding delete & search functions.

One advantage of using the struct is you can use shorter names, e.g.:

```
struct name_list_t { 
       char **array; 
       size_t n, capacity; } names = { .array = NULL };
```

> //this function works, when freed inside main()

Meh.  The comment doesn't really make sense, because functions aren't freed.  I get what you mean, but you're making me work.

HTH.